# Powerline: how to show whether buffer is modified more prominently

Tags: powerline

I've just installed [powerline](https://github.com/milkypostman/powerline) to update my emacs looks for the 21. century.
I like it, but I'm bothered that the modified-buffer indicator is just a simple, barely discernible asterisk.

Is there a way to make the fact that the buffer is modified to be more eye-catching?

My config up to now is very simple:

```
(use-package powerline
  :config
  (setq powerline-display-buffer-size nil)
  (setq powerline-display-mule-info nil)
  (setq powerline-display-hud nil)
  (which-function-mode)
  (when (display-graphic-p)
    (powerline-default-theme)))
```

Is there a simple way to change certain faces without creating custom poweline themes (I also don't like the color of the (which-function-mode) output.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please provide a link to "Powerline". That can help others help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- I use [spaceline](https://github.com/TheBB/spaceline).

  Basically it's built on top of `powerline` and let you build your mode-line by adding several segments one after the other (in both left and right sections).

  For instance, the following segment: `(major-mode :face highlight-face)` will insert the current major mode and apply a special face to it. This face `highlight-face` changes following several criterias. You can customize `spaceline-modified`, `spaceline-read-only` and `spaceline-unmodified` faces to fix your issue.
- If you still want to use `powerline`, you need to do what `spaceline` already does. That is to check for buffer status and apply the face you want. See `buffer-read-only` and `buffer-modified-p`.

Here is how my mode-line looks like:

*Normal*
[image]
*Modified*
[image]
*Read-only*
[image]
*Helm*
[image]

Comment: It isn't clear to me how exactly to get `spaceline` to produce something like your screeshots.  Could you share your config?

Comment: Sure, [there you go](https://github.com/angrybacon/dotemacs/blob/master/dotemacs.org#12-mode-line). :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Here is my spaceline configuration in totality to achieve the modified buffer objective:

```
  (require 'spaceline-config)
  (spaceline-emacs-theme)
  (setq spaceline-highlight-face-func 'spaceline-highlight-face-modified)
```

Then customize the face, say, via `M-x customize` or:

```
(custom-set-faces
 '(spaceline-modified ((t (:background "OrangeRed" :foreground "#3E3D31"
                                       :inherit (quote mode-line))))))
```